# How to configure WiFi on RPi 3B before first start?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh

So we have a [how-to](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/55971/36605), yet it works only when OS was already installed. In case when the device is fresh and .iso (say raspberian) was just flashed sctipts differ: there is no `wpa_supplicant` folder and `interfaces` looks diferently.

How to set WiFi configuration **before** first insertion of flashed raspberian into WiFi capable RPi 3 device (I have only WiFi in my router)?

Comment: You don't mention what OS you used to burn the card but this will work with Linux https://davidmaitland.me/2015/12/raspberry-pi-zero-headless-setup/. If you don't have a Linux box you can always use a live CD.

Comment: Windows+raspberian+Paragon ExtFS

Comment: If you are up to the challenge you could try out [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/docs.html) to make your own customized build with the required settings. I must mention, the process is time consuming and  requires a reasonably powerful system to be able to quickly run change-build-deploy-test cycles. There are also config files specific to raspberry pi 1/2/3 which should help you get started

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [THE LATEST UPDATE TO RASPBIAN](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/) it can be done easily. Just place your WiFi configuration on the freshly burned SD card:

> If a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file is placed into the `/boot/` directory, this will be moved to the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/` directory the next time the system is booted, overwriting the network settings; this allows a Wifi configuration to be preloaded onto a card from a Windows or other machine that can only see the boot partition.